# How to import js modules into python?

Tags: python, node.js

I am having a function in a js file which uses an npm library and provides some response. Now since my app is running on python, I intend to use this js function from a python script.

eg:- I have a file `pure.js`

```
function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

the python file --> `main.py`

```
import pure
print(pure.add(5, 7))
```

is there any way to use the add function from the pure.js file in main.py?

Comment: There shouldn't be any need to use a javascript module in python, what are you really trying to do

Comment: I need to use the following npm library - https://github.com/json-schema-faker/json-schema-faker. This library provides a valid sample JSON for the given JSON-schema.
After obtaining the sample from the js file I need to utilize in my python app